# JTree disable/overwrite TransferHandler keyboard actions

Tags: java, swing, jtree, drag-and-drop, key-events

I need to get rid of standard keyboard action handler of TransferHandler class I use for my JTree.
The JTree implements access-level mechanism that controls if node may or may not be deleted. This behavior is neglected by using keyboard combinations like shift-delete allowing each user to deletre any node from the JTree.

Basically I need the TransferHandler to provide a convenient way of moving and sorting nodes (DnD). That's it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I'm late, lbalazscs already suggested above.

You can try something like this:

```
JTree tree = new JTree();
tree.setDragEnabled(true);
tree.setDropMode(DropMode.ON_OR_INSERT);
tree.setTransferHandler(new YourTreeTransferHandler());
//......
Object key = TransferHandler.getCutAction().getValue(Action.NAME);
System.out.println(key);
tree.getActionMap().put(key, new AbstractAction() {
  @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println("dummy");
  }
});
```

Comment: Even though the solution has already been suggested I like this way better. Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can remove key default bindings by removing them form the [ActionMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ActionMap.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

Something like this:

```
ActionMap actionMap = tree.getActionMap();
actionMap.remove("cut");
actionMap.getParent().remove("cut");
actionMap.remove("copy");
actionMap.getParent().remove("copy");
actionMap.remove("paste");
actionMap.getParent().remove("paste");
```